# Project Euler #14: What's wrong with this code?

Tags: c

**This is related to the "Project Euler Problem 14"**

As I think, my logic and the code is good enough,but it may take few seconds to give the answer.
But when i run this code, the program stops when "starting_number" is around 103152(i can't remember the number exactly).

Can anybody please have a look at this code and, tell me where and what's wrong with this code.

Here's the code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
int starting_number;
int number_of_terms;
int j=0,k=0;
int term;

int main(){
  for(starting_number=2;starting_number<1000000;starting_number++){
    term = starting_number;
    number_of_terms = 1;

    while(1){
      {
        if(term%2==0){
          term = term/2;
          number_of_terms++;
        } else if(term%2!=0){
          term = 3*term + 1;
          number_of_terms++;
        }
      }
      if(term == 1) break;    
    }


    if(j>=number_of_terms)   //finding which chain is longer
      j=j;
    else if(j< number_of_terms) {
      j= number_of_terms;
      k=starting_number;
    }

    printf("\n%d",starting_number);
  } 

  printf("\n%d(%d)\n",k,j);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What have you done to try and solve the problem?

Comment: I went through and reindented all of your code. It's much easier to read now. Remember, reduce whitespace in your code does not make it run faster, but may make your brain run slower.

Comment: I am no expert but ... if(j>=number_of_terms) j=j; leaves me wondering

Comment: SO is not a substitute for a debugging session.

Comment: Can your machine hold 1000000 in int?

Comment: Not the issue, @silentboy, but close. The problem is that the Collatz sequence may reach to _much_ higher numbers before collapsing back to 1. The problem is with one of the intermediate values overflowing.

Comment: I definitely recommend using Python to do Project Euler. It's much more flexible in number variable types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one's mildly tricky, but your problem is here:

```
if(term == 1) break;
```

If the variable `term` becomes very large (as it can easily do) then it can overflow the `int` datatype.

When this happens `term` becomes negative. The C language modulus of a negative odd number is itself negative. Therefore, the end condition for your loop is never met.

Solve this problem by using a larger data type such as `unsigned long long`.

A less convoluted version of your code would appear as follows. Note that I have eliminated the global variables (those outside of your `main` function) because global variables [are evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad). I've replaced your infinite while-loop with a loop that uses an end condition. I've reduced duplication of code within the while-loop. I've eliminated the `j=j` case. Since `printf` is a slow function to run, I've commented out the `prinft` you had in the `for` loop, which improves the run-time significantly.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  int number_of_terms;
  unsigned long long term;
  int j=0,k=0;

  for(int starting_number=2;starting_number<1000000;++starting_number){
    term = starting_number;
    number_of_terms = 1;

    while(term!=1){
      if(term%2==0)
        term /= 2;
      else
        term = 3*term + 1;
      number_of_terms++;
    }

    if(j<number_of_terms){   //finding which chain is longer
      j = number_of_terms;
      k = starting_number;
    }

    //printf("\n%d",starting_number);
  } 

  printf("\n%d(%d)\n",k,j);
  return 0;
}
```

And, indeed, using `unsigned long long` solves the problem.

Comment: But the variety of values which can be assigned as an integer(int) runs from - 2147483647 to + 2147483647. i don't think that the value of "term" will run higher than that

Comment: @DennisMeng, since the OP did not know exactly which starting number was causing the issue, it is certainly possible that a different number was a fault. This does not change the fact that an overflow can be used to construct an infinite loop in this situation.

Comment: :) thanks! your logic was right. unsigned long long, solves the problem and yes, i could have reduced the code as you said. thanks again

Comment: @Ime94, you're welcome. Often times it is the case that reducing and cleaning up the code will help you find solutions or even mysteriously solve problems. Failing to properly indent and reduce code is slapping everyone who might help you in the face because the first thing we're going to do is clean your code, and it's unkind of you to waste our time by having us do something you were capable of doing yourself.